# Division by zero error votes

Tags: php

I am trying to implement a voting system, when a user clicks one of the hyperlinks the page refreshes and the database should be updated with the database information, I was getting a division by zero error which is no longer the case due to the conditional statement included, however the votes don't work and the database doesn't get updated when a user clicks one of the hyper links.

```
<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("dbname") or die(mysql_error()); 

  //We only run this code if the user has just clicked a voting link
 if ( $mode=="vote") 
 { 

 //If the user has already voted on the particular thing, we do not allow them to vote again    

 $cookie = "Mysite$id"; 
 if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie])) 
    { 
    Echo "Sorry You have already ranked that site <p>"; 
    } 

  //Otherwise, we set a cooking telling us they have now voted 
else 
    { 
    $month = 2592000 + time(); 
    setcookie(Mysite.$id, Voted, $month); 

     //Then we update the voting information by adding 1 to the total votes and adding their vote (1,2,3,etc) to the total rating 
 mysql_query ("UPDATE reports SET total = total + $voted, votes = votes + 1 WHERE reportID = $id"); 
    Echo "Your vote has been cast <p>"; 
    } 
 } 

 //Puts SQL Data into an array
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reports WHERE reportID = $id") or die(mysql_error()); 

 //Now we loop through all the data 
 while($ratings = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 //This outputs the sites name 
 Echo "Name: " .$ratings['reportName']."<br>"; 

  //This calculates the sites ranking and then outputs it - rounded to 1 decimal 


if(isset($ratings['votes']) && $ratings['votes'] != 0){
  $current = $ratings['total'] / $ratings['votes']; 
  Echo "Current Rating: " . round($current, 1) . "<br>"; 
}



 //This creates 5 links to vote a 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 rating for each particular item 
 Echo "Rank Me: "; 
 Echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=1&id=".$ratings['reportID'].">Vote 1</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=2&id=".$ratings['reportID'].">Vote 2</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=3&id=".$ratings['reportID'].">Vote 3</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=4&id=".$ratings['reportID'].">Vote 4</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?mode=vote&voted=5&id=".$ratings['reportID'].">Vote 5</a><p>"; 
 } 
 ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `$ratings[votes]` is 0. Find out why.

Comment: Incidentally, you're missing the quotes around `'total'` and `'votes'` (that PHP allows this is a historical accident, and that it's not a shoutier warning is one of my pet peeves).

Comment: In case you don't understand why this is an error, try calculating `42 / 0` on a calculator, or on paper, or anywhere. It is an equation with no sane answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the value of `$ratings[votes]` first before doing division operation.

```
if(isset($ratings[votes]) && $ratings[votes] != 0){
    $current = $ratings[total] / $ratings[votes]; 
    Echo "Current Rating: " . round($current, 1) . "<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to check `$rating['total']` has a sane value to, depending where these values came from.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: in my database the field is default set to zero, may this be causing the error?

Comment: @user3296793 yes. But thats ok. You can check this from your `PHP` end.